# JMS Vs JPPF (Java Parallel Processing) Frameworks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parallel-processing, jms, jppf

Can anybody share their knowledge on JMS & JPPF framework?
( eg. Which one is best for certain requirement, difference between these two frameworks ? )

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is for asynchronous communication.
e.g. EMAIL, the sender is decoupled from the receiver

JPPF is basically an approach in which a task is split into sub-tasks so that the can be processed in parallel.

JMS/JPPF can be used together 
e.g. you have a long running task
refactor step 1. introduce JMS(e.g. MDB) so that you can fire and do not have to wait for the task to complete
refactor step 2. the time taken for task to complete based on above refactoring does not change, so you could in fact use JPPF approach say with AsynchBeans etc to process the task in parallel.

HTH